# Commuting operators with no eigenstates in common: infinite potential well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

The eigenstates for the infinite potential well described by the Hamiltonian 
$$ \hat{H}= \frac{\hat{P}^2}{2m} + V(x),\, V(x) = \begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x <0$} \\
\infty, & \text{if $x>L$}
\end{cases}
$$
are $$\Psi_n(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$$

Now, if two operators $\hat{A},\hat{B}$ commute, they have eigenstates in common. $\hat{H}$ and $\hat{P}$ commute but they do not have simultaneous eigenstates. Why?

Answer (score -1):

Hamiltonian does not commute with momentum operator .It only commutes if potential is zero.
For more details check
https://www.quora.com/When-does-the-Hamiltonian-H-commute-with-the-momentum-P-How-can-I-prove-that-H-P-0